# Laravel Eloquent ORM Pagination + Vue.js Component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on this Laravel Project where I load a component `activities-table` with the main Vue instance data called from an API where I use Eloquent ORM Pagination. But the `ActivitiesTable.data` is *undefined*:

So, first I have my API on http://app.local/api/activities

```
public function getActivities()
{
    $activities = Activity::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(100);

    foreach($activities as $k => $activity)
    {
        $data = [
            'user' => isset($activity->user) ? $activity->user->name : NULL,
            'avatar' => isset($activity->user) ? $activity->user->avatar : NULL,
            'ip' => $activity->remote_addr,
            'country' => $activity->country,
            'referer' => $activity->referer,
            'action' => $activity->request_uri,
            'date' => $activity->created_at->toDateTimeString(),
            'timeago' => $activity->created_at->diffForHumans()
        ];

        $activities[$k]->custom_data = $data;
    }

    return $activities;
}
```

Then I have my main Vue instance method where I call the API on the file app.js:

```
loadActivities: function(page = 1) {
    axios.get('/api/activities?page=' + page)
        .then(function (response) {
            app.activities = response.data;
        });
},
```

So this is how activities seems on Vue Tool:

[image: activities on Vue]

So, this is my component that is already registered on **app.js**:

```
<template>
    <!-- Activities -->
    <table id="activities">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            ...columns...
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ...data...
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- /Activities -->
</template>

<script>
    module.exports = {
        props: {
            rows: {

            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                data: this.rows
            }
        },
        created: function() {

        },
        methods: {
            paginate: function(page) {

            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

And then here is the `<activities-table>` component:

```
<activities-table
    :rows="this.activities"
    ></activities-table>
```

I get the result in the same Vue Tool:

[image: data in Vue]

I already tried to assign `this.data = this.rows` in the `created` hook, or try different lifecycle hooks but always is undefined or an empty array.

This is what `console.log(this.data)` on the Vue component displays:

[image: developer tool]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, and if you will do the same thing in the `mounted` hook, for example, manually assign some variable to your data like `this.somevar=true`, Will it works? Will it be displayed or not?

Comment: thanks for commenting.. If I manually assign to some variable a value it is displayed in `mounted` hook.

Comment: so you are assigning the full response object as the activities however this is not correct. `this.activities = response.data.data` (unless you want that data with it) will be the custom data you are returning. the rest is for pagination